# Function syntaxis meaning

Tags: r, function, syntax

In this function, what do `wx=x` and `wy=y` mean? That wx and wy are optional so I can write: `formula(x,y)` without wx and wy?

```
formula <- function(x, y, wx = x, wy = y){
  z <- x * (1 - x)
  t <- y * (1 - y)
  
  wz <- wx * (1 - wx)
  wt <- wy * (1 - wx)
  
  k <- z + t
  l <- k/2
  
  return((wx - wy)/sqrt(l))
}
```

Comment: yes they are default values

Comment: Test `ff <- function(x, y=x) c(x,y)`. Output with one argument `ff(1) [1] 1 1`, output with 2 arguments `ff(1, 2) [1] 1 2`. Bottom line, you can set `wx` and `wy` if necessary, but you don't have to. If you remove `wx`/`wy` you cannot set them separately.

Comment: Thank you both. @AndreWildberg so if I want to put some non mandatory values in the function, I just write something like formula <- function(a,b, c=a, d=b) so that if c and d are assente the lines of code in the function which contain c and d are replaced by a and b, correct?

Comment: @user19745561 If you set them to another variable you can see them as non-mandatory, yes. The more common way to use this feature is to set them to default values, e.g. `function(x, y=23)`. This way `y` is mandatory, yet still resettable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you see `function(a = 1, b = 2) { ... }` it means `1` and `2` are the default values. You can't write directly `formula(x,y)`, even though this is common in other functional programming languages. You can use anonymous functions and lambdas:

```r
# lambda
purrr::map(1:10, ~ log(.x, base = 1))

# anonymous function
purrr::map(1:10, function(n) { n %% 2 == 0 })

# contrived way of turning a lambda into an anonymous function using currying
purrr::as_mapper(~ .x + 1)(1)
```